# Beamer tikz uncovering with different fill colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, color, tikz-trees

Consider the following slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,0}]{structure}
}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz, nth}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,bending,positioning, chains}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example: AVL Trees}
\uncover<+->{{\bf Solution: \\~\\}
\uncover<+->{{\bf Recall:} The balance factor of a node is equal to the height of the right subtree minus the height of the left subtree. \\~\\}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\uncover<+->{
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  level distance=15 pt,
  every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\scriptsize},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=150 pt},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=70 pt},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=60 pt}%
]
  \node {{\uncover<8->{-1}}}
    child {node {{\uncover<7->{-1}}}
      child {node {{\uncover<6->{1}}}
        child {node {{\uncover<4->{0}}}}
        child {node {{\uncover<5->{0}}}
          child {node {{\uncover<4->{0}}}}
          child {node {{\uncover<4->{0}}}}
        }
      }
      child {node {{\uncover<7->{1}}}
        child {edge from parent[draw=none]}
        child {node {{\uncover<4->{0}}}}
      }
    }
    child {node {{\uncover<6->{1}}}
      child {node {{\uncover<4->{0}}}}
      child {node {{\uncover<5->{-1}}}
        child {node {{\uncover<4->{0}}}}
        child {edge from parent[draw=none]}
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add a fill color option to the nodes that are currently being uncovered. So for example, when I uncover those with <4->, I want them to be red. But when I uncover the next ones <5->, I do not what the <4-> to be red anymore, just the newly uncovered ones. Likewise when I uncover <6-> and so forth. What's the easiest way to do this? I can't get them to change back after setting them to be red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\alert<>{}` to specify the slides on which the text should be shown 'alerted'. By default, this happens to be red.

For example (and simplifying the code and MWE a bit):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}
  \usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,0}]{structure}
}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example: AVL Trees}
  \onslide<+->
  \textbf{Solution:}
  \bigskip\par
  \onslide<+->
  \textbf{Recall:} The balance factor of a node is equal to the height of the right subtree minus the height of the left subtree.
  \bigskip\par
  \begin{center}
    \onslide<+->
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
      level distance=15 pt,
      every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\scriptsize},
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=150 pt},
      level 2/.style={sibling distance=70 pt},
      level 3/.style={sibling distance=60 pt}%
      ]
      \node {{\uncover<8->{\alert<8>{-1}}}}
      child {node {{\uncover<7->{\alert<7>{-1}}}}
        child {node {{\uncover<6->{\alert<6>{1}}}}
          child {node {{\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{0}}}}}
          child {node {{\uncover<5->{\alert<5>{0}}}}
            child {node {{\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{0}}}}}
            child {node {{\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{0}}}}}
          }
        }
        child {node {{\uncover<7->{\alert<7>{1}}}}
          child {edge from parent[draw=none]}
          child {node {{\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{0}}}}}
        }
      }
      child {node {{\uncover<6->{\alert<6>1}}}
        child {node {{\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{0}}}}}
        child {node {{\uncover<5->{\alert<5>{-1}}}}
          child {node {{\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{0}}}}}
          child {edge from parent[draw=none]}
        }
      }
      ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: alerted nodes in tree]

I'd use Forest for the tree, but you can do without it here ;).